# Sort list of tuples by specific tuple element in Python 3

Tags: python, list, search, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
tple_list = [('4', '4', '1', 'Bart', 'Simpson'), 
('1', '2', '6', 'Lisa', 'Simpson'), 
('6', '3', '4', 'Homer', 'Simpson'), 
('2', '3', '1', 'Hermione', 'Nobody'), 
('1', '2', '3', 'Bristol', 'Palace')]
```

I want to sort them all by their last name's. If the last names of two student's are the same, then I'd like to search by the first name. How?

Thanks.

========================

So, I've got this so far:

```
tple_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(4), reverse=False)
```

This takes the list and sorts it by last name. I have people with the same last name though, so how do I sort by their first name if their last name is the same?

Comment: use `itemgetter(4, 3)`

Comment: @rpattiso add that as an answer for future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `itemgetter` from Python's [operator module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) to sort using multiple indices in any order.

```
from operator import itemgetter

tple_list = [('4', '4', '1', 'Bart', 'Simpson'), 
('1', '2', '6', 'Lisa', 'Simpson'), 
('6', '3', '4', 'Homer', 'Simpson'), 
('2', '3', '1', 'Hermione', 'Nobody'), 
('1', '2', '3', 'Bristol', 'Palace')]

tple_list.sort(key=itemgetter(4, 3)) # lastname, firstname
print(tple_list)
```

output

```
[('2', '3', '1', 'Hermione', 'Nobody'),
 ('1', '2', '3', 'Bristol', 'Palace'),
('4', '4', '1', 'Bart', 'Simpson'),
('6', '3', '4', 'Homer', 'Simpson'),
('1', '2', '6', 'Lisa', 'Simpson')]
```